# Do Ubuntu Qt5 maintainers know it ships with Vulkan disabled?

Tags: 18.10

Ubuntu 18.10 ships with Qt 5.11 which should support Vulkan.

If Qt5 gets built on a host that doesn't support Vulkan its support will get disabled, to fix this issue it has to be built on a host with Vulkan support.

To workaround this issue I built & installed Qt5 from source and linked to it from my project.

Btw. Fedora 29 has this issue too.

I'm wondering about the question in the title.